# Why strptime() is not working in my for loop?

Tags: python, csv

I am using python to extract day from dates in given csv file.

This is my code:

```
import csv

filename = "no.csv"

fields = []             
rows = []              

with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
  csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

  fields = csvreader.next()       
  for row in csvreader:          
    rows.append(row)

  for i in rows[0:2]:
      print i

  import datetime
  from datetime import timedelta
  import time

  d = datetime.datetime.strptime(rows[4][3],'\xa0%d/%m/%Y')
  print d.day 

  for j in range(len(rows)):
      d = datetime.datetime.strptime(rows[j][3],'\xa0%d/%m/%Y')
      print d.day
```

And in my output, in `strptime()` if I use `rows[4][3]` to mention the date which is in csv file, I am getting output. But, if I use it in for loop, it showing me error in format.

```
['', '', '(Time)', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['\xa0Nitric Oxide(NO)', '\xa000:00:00', '\xa000:14:00', '\xa001/01/2017', '120.1', '\xa0\xb5g/m\xb3', 'NA', 'NA', '']
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RAJESH/Desktop/csv stuff.py", line 26, in <module>
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(rows[j][3],'\xa0%d/%m/%Y')
  File "C:\Python26\lib\_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '\xa0%d/%m/%Y'
```

I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Don't link to images of code. Post the code *here*, as *text*.

Comment: Post your error message as text too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **omit first row** when iterating since I believe it's header of this file and it does not contain date in format you provide in `strptime`:

```
for i in range(1, len(rows)):
    ...
```

Also it would be better to make sure data is in proper format each iteratoin before calling `strptime`.

Comment: Thank you I got it.